# Removing duplicate rows when only the date is different

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm going through a listing that has about 600 rows and it lists everyone who completed a training but it list multiple days if they did it more than once. I want to keep each row that has the newest date. For example below John Adams completed Class A on 11/17/2021 and 11/23/2022. I want to remove the row with 11/17/2021 and keep 11/23/2022. Same for Schrute, Dwight who has 3 dates, I only want to keep 01/18/2023. I'll be using the solution to build into a Macro to make the process smother as I have to do this through multiple tabs of the report.

[image: Example]

Comment: Sort on the date column descending.  Then use the Remove Duplicate tool on the data tab using all the other columns as the duplicate rule.

Comment: @Scott Craner's answer is easier than the one I proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select data range and sort as follows
   [image]
2. Select column A and insert a new column
   [image]
3. Add the following formulas into A column (you can enter A3 and then copy/drag
   [image]
   [image]
4. Select column A and copy

[image]

5. Select column A and paste VALUES

[image]

6. Select data range and sort as follows

[image]

7. Select the rows with a "1" in column A and delete the rows

[image]

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much!

Comment: @SlyWolf, If the solution answers your problem, please mark the "check mark" as being answered. Thank you.